# Pentaho - upload file using API

Tags: pentaho, pdi, spoon

I need to upload a file using an API.

I tried REST CLIENT and didn't find any options. 
Tried with HTTP POST and that responded with 415.

Please suggest how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this  by using the solution from http://www.dietz-solutions.com/2017/06/pentaho-data-integration-multi-part.html

Thanks Ben.

He's written a Java class for Multi-part Form submission. I extendd by adding a header for Authorization...

Answer (score 1):

Error 415 is “Unsupported media type”. 
You may need to change the media type of the request or check whether that type of file us accepted by the remote server.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: i did set content type as multipart/form-data, but getting same response. While checking with Postman, i removed the header for content ttype and it was able to upload. If i dont set a content type, it automatically sets it as Text/xml. Atleast if i can get http post not to set content-type it might be useful.

Also, though it may be seem naive is there another way of doing this? other than using HTTp post

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses only standard classes of jre 7. Add a step `Modified Java Script Value` in your transformation. You will have to add two columns in the flow: `URL_FORM_POST_MULTIPART_COLUMN` and `FILE_URL_COLUMN`, you can add as many files as you want, you will just have to call `outputStreamToRequestBody.write` more times.

```
    try
    {
        //in this step you will need to add two columns from the previous flow -> URL_FORM_POST_MULTIPART_COLUMN, FILE_URL_COLUMN 
        var serverUrl =  new java.net.URL(URL_FORM_POST_MULTIPART_COLUMN);

        var boundaryString = "999aaa000zzz09za";
        var openBoundary  = java.lang.String.format("\n\n--%s\nContent-Disposition: form-data\nContent-Type: text/xml\n\n" , boundaryString);
        var closeBoundary = java.lang.String.format("\n\n--%s--\n", boundaryString);

        // var netIPSocketAddress = java.net.InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8888);
        // var proxy = java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP , netIPSocketAddress);
        // var urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection(proxy);
        var urlConnection = serverUrl.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Indicate that we want to write to the HTTP request body
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        //urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Authorization);
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryString);


        var outputStreamToRequestBody = urlConnection.getOutputStream();

        outputStreamToRequestBody.write(openBoundary.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        outputStreamToRequestBody.write(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Paths.get(FILE_URL_COLUMN)));
        outputStreamToRequestBody.write(closeBoundary.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        outputStreamToRequestBody.flush();


        var httpResponseReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        var lineRead = "";
        var finalText = "";
        while((lineRead = httpResponseReader.readLine()) != null) {
            finalText += lineRead;
        }

        var status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        var result = finalText;
        var time   = new Date();

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        Alert(e);
    }
```